# Local Files behave differently than remote CDN files

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to include openlayers in a nativescript app inside a webview. This works fine for the most part. So far I used remote CDN files to get openlayers in the webview. When I change this line

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>`

to this line

`<script src="./js/external/ol.js"></script>`

The image icons in openlayers do not work properly anymore (See images below). When I open the html file in Chrome on my laptop it works fine either way. Why is the Webview behaving differently when I use a local file?

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/ll9/ol-local-cdns

Update: Wow, apparently one can not post inline images when you do not have enough Stackoverflow points so here are the images as plain links:

Local file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ll9/ol-local-cdns/master/ol-fail.png

Remote:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ll9/ol-local-cdns/master/ol-ok.png

Comment: For security reasons, access to local resources won't be enabled in iOS. By default {N} WebView allows access to local files (JS, CSS, and Images) only from the same path where your HTML file is placed and the paths has to be absolute.

Comment: I think this does not apply in my case. I am using android and the javascript file loads for the most part. It's just that the icons behave strange (+-icon even loads properly for example)

Comment: You are probably missing a charset meta tag.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783494/openlayers-5-1-3-damaged-zoom-out-button-in-quick-start-example

Comment: Thank you, adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` fixed the problem. I still find it strage that it worked using a remote file either way.

Comment: @Mike Would you mind posting the same as answer so it may easily help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers uses UTF-8 for some of characters on control buttons (instead of using html codes such as `&minus;`).  The CDN libraries are saved in UTF format, but any created or edited by other means might not be.  Inserting a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in the html header will ensure the browser correctly interprets any such scripts regardless of their origin.  See also [openlayers 5.1.3: "Damaged" zoom out button in quick start example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783494/openlayers-5-1-3-damaged-zoom-out-button-in-quick-start-example)