# encoding problem when OpenLayers is loaded from web host

Tags: character-encoding, webserver, openlayers, mouse-position

I'm working on a web based GIS using OpenLayers 7.1.0.
When testing the code with VS-Code on my laptop (loading ol.js from local hard drive) everything is ok.
Then I upload the project to a Linux web host (Plesk panel) including ol.js because I want it to work independent of OpenLayers CDN.
Now, if ol.js is loaded from CDN, everything is OK. But if ol.js is loaded from the web host, characters showing the mouse pointer position are not shown correctly. screenshot is attached.
In both cases, the same css file is loaded from my web host.
what might be the problem ?

[image: Screenshot attached]

Is it possible that the web server on my Linux host changes something ?

Comment: Thank you JGH for embedding the picture !

Comment: Adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your html should fix it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016347/10118270

Comment: Mike, you're awesome ! This is the second problem you solved for me in 24 hours !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is from [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike):

Adding meta charset="UTF-8" to your html should fix it, see [stackoverflow.com/a/52016347/10118270](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016347/10118270)